# Ef Core Linq Query ThenInclude throwing InvalidOperationException: The EF.Property<T> method may only be used within LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to get a completely filled User object including the related table Adress and then include Plz_Ort.

```
public partial class User
{
    //No hash sets for Adress Scaffolded (probably unnecessary since the is 
    //only ever one address per user

    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public int? FidAdresse { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachmname { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FidAdresse")]
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual Adresse FidAdresseNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Adresse
{
    public Adresse()
    {
        User = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int IdAdresse { get; set; }
    public int FidPlzOrt { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public string Hausnr { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FidPlzOrt")]
    [InverseProperty("Adresse")]
    public virtual PlzOrt FidPlzOrtNavigation { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("FidAdresseNavigation")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}

public partial class PlzOrt
{
    public PlzOrt()
    {
        Adresse = new HashSet<Adresse>();
    }

    public int IdPlzOrt { get; set; }
    public string Plz { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("FidPlzOrtNavigation")]
    public virtual ICollection<Adresse> Adresse { get; set; }
}
```

The relationships are as follows User 1:1 Adress and Adress n:1 Plz_ort.

I then make a linq query which throws the **Exception: 'The EF.Property method may only be used within LINQ queries.'**

```
return _context.User
            .Include(u => u.FidPermissionNavigation)
            .Include(c => c.FidAdresseNavigation)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.FidPlzOrtNavigation)
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdUser == id);
```

This query works whe I comment out the "theninclude(c => c.FidPlzOrtNavigation)". I get an object with the plznavigation set as null.

This query works fine.

```
return _context.Adresse
            .Include(c => c.FidPlzOrtNavigation)
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdAdresse == idAddresse);
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Or should I generally not try to query objects with so much related data?

**UPDATE**

I scaffolded all these tables DB First with Pomelo. Apparently, the scaffold ignored all my 1:1 relationships and decided to make them all 1:n. Here´s the generated code for the dbcontext.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IdUser)
                    .HasName("PRIMARY");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.FidAdresse)
                    .HasName("fk_User_Adresse1_idx");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.FidAdresseNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.User)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FidAdresse)
                    .HasConstraintName("fk_User_Adresse1");
            });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Adresse>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IdAdresse)
                    .HasName("PRIMARY");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.FidPlzOrt)
                    .HasName("fk_Adresse_plz_ort1_idx");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.FidPlzOrtNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Adresse)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FidPlzOrt)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("fk_Adresse_plz_ort1");
            });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PlzOrt>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IdPlzOrt)
                    .HasName("PRIMARY");
            });
```

In case the scaffold created the wrong relationship on the entities, I will update this post to a new title and refrase this post.

**All my 1:1 relationships are defined as non-identifying**
How to get Pomelo to scaffold 1:1 relationships properly? I tried deleting and adding the 1:1 relationship between user and adress and syncronized the changes of the EER with the DB. Afterwards I scaffolded the changes with --force so the Entities would be overwritten, but the DBContext still did not change the Entity at all.

Comment: You have a collection (ICollection<User>).  Probably using a JOIN instead of an INCLUDE would work.

Comment: Before including "join" in my linq queries I am going to try to scaffold the DB so that the relationship between User and Address is shown correctly (without a collection in the inverse navigation property of address to user). I am supposed to never need join if the navigation properties are correctly implemented in my code.

Comment: Do you have fluent configuration not shown here? The model as posted is invalid because EF cannot determine the PKs. Also remove the `Include`s of entities not shown. What you are explaining normally does not happen, so make sure to provide [mcve], i.e. something that we can copy/paste in a clean project and run. The minimum to include is the relevant entity classes and related fluent configuration if any.

Comment: Do you mean the dbcontext by "fluent configuration"?

Comment: I think you want following : .Include(c => c.FidAnredeNavigation.Where(u => u.IdUser == id)) and then eliminate last line.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't let me use Where after FidAdresseNavigation. It only offers the Properties and the Inverse Property to Adresse.